# Android GCM onHandleIntent

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm facing an issue regarding Android GCM.
The below code works fine on ANDROID 4.4, but when I try it on ANDROID 4.0 it doesnt.

Here is how my app works:

**PHP page sents GCM Message**

```
$message = array("type" => 1, "code" => 9999);

$registrationIDs = array();
$registrationIDs[] = $gcmid; //device already registered successfully

$this->gcm->send_notification($registrationIDs,$message);
```

**Application receives the GCM notification and enters on onHandleIntent**

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();


if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
    String stype = extras.getString("type");
```

Here it is where I couldnt understand. The value of the var extras is different for each device. Looks like the device 4.0 is not registered, but actually it received the GCM message without the data values.

**ANDROID 4.4 response**

```
Bundle[{code=9999, from=177887891705, type=1, android.support.content.wakelockid=1, collapse_key=do_not_collapse}]
```

**ANDROID 4.0 response**

```
Bundle[{android.support.content.wakelockid=1, unregistered=com.mypackage.test}]
```

Again, I'm testing using the same code for both devices (sure, the GCM Registration ID are different for each device).

Does anyone have any hint to share about this?

Thank you!

Comment: Please post your manifest

Comment: I also got the same kind of issue.,
you may be missed your package name inside the Broadcast receiver category..

if your packagename is com.sample.example
Your BroadcastReceiver in Manifest is like below

<receiver            android:name="com.sample.example.GCMBroadcastReceiver"            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
 <category android:name="com.sample.example" />

</intent-filter>

</receiver>

Comment: Can you post the LogCat output for the device that is not getting the msg? it may shed a bit of light about what's happening under the hood.